# Normal basis in cyclotomic number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Let $p$ be an odd prime integer and let $\zeta$ be a primitive $2p$-th root of unity. Does $\alpha=1+\zeta+\zeta^{-1}+\dots+\zeta^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+\zeta^{-\frac{p-1}{2}}$ generates a normal basis of $Q(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$.
In other words does the Galois conjugates of $\alpha$ form a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$?

Comment: Have you tried writing down some of its conjugates?

Comment: Yes! I also have verified that $\alpha$ generates a normal basis for all the odd primes up $p\le 1700$. But I don't have a clue why $\alpha$ always generates a normal basis.

Comment: I encountered this question when studying the Zassenhaus Conjecture on torsion units of integral group rings of some finite groups.

Comment: I haven't given this too much thought, but I would've thought the natural approach would've been to write the conjugates in terms of the standard power basis, and then show that the matrix of coefficients was invertible.

Comment: Dear Cam, thank you for the hint. I tried to do what you suggest but I don't see any regularity in the matrix of coefficients which can help to obtain . Well, writing $\alpha$ in a power basis (for example, $1$, $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$, $(\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2}$, $\dots$, seems a bit messy. This is why I prefer to use that more "suitable" basis $b_1=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}, \dots, b_{\frac{p-1}{2}}=\zeta^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+\zeta^{-\frac{p-1}{2}}$. Then the coefficient matrix is formed by rows formed with 0 and -2, (0 or 1 more -2).

Comment: Observe that the original basis is the normal basis generated by $b=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$. Taking a generator $\sigma$ of the Galois group and reordering the origianal basis as $\{\sigma^i(b):i=0,1,\dots,\frac{p-1}{2}\}$ one can see see the coefficient matrix as a circulant matrix. This reduces to see if the polynomial $P$ with coefficients the first row of the circulant matrix has a root which is a $\frac{p-1}{2}$ root of unity, but I don't see how to prove the latter because I don't see regularity on the polynomial $P$.

Comment: Also posted as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/202321/polynomial-generated-with-primitive-element-modulo-p

Comment: Another equivalent form of the question: Let $k\mod p$ denote the representative of $k$ modulo $p$ in the interval $[-n,n]$ where $n=\frac{p−1}{2}$. Consider the $n\times n$ matrix having $1$ in the $(i,j)$-th entry if $ij \mod p$ is odd and $0$ otherwise. Is A invertible in the ring of rational matrices?

Comment: The answer is positive. I got a solution by René Schoof. The solution is too long to include it here. I will include it in a paper that I am writing.

Comment: Link to the paper, please?